# Why is using a macro in my code produces errors?

Tags: c, macros, bit, indexed

I wrote a macro that sums the number of odd indexed bits which are turned on.

A few examples:

In the variable that contains the following bits:

```
10010101
```

Only the bit at index 7 is turned on, there is only 1 odd indexed bit that is turned on,so the answer is 1.

In the variable that contains the following bits:

```
00101011
```

Bit at index 1 is turned on, bit at index 3 is turned on and bit at index 5 is turned on, and therefore there is a total of 3 odd indexed bits that are turned on, so the answer is 3.

I wrote a main function to test this macro.

Here's the entire program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ODD(n)\
 int count = 0;\
 int i = 1; \
while(n>>i)\
{\
    if( ((n>>i)%2) == 1)\
        count++;\
        i = i+2;\
}\




int main()
{
  int i;
  int j;
  int array1[] = {1,2,3,4};
 /*array1 contains (binary representation):
  00000001
  00000010
  00000011
  00000100
  After passing these into the macro:
  00000001 ----> 0 odd indexed bits are turned on
  00000010 ---->1 odd indexed bit is turned on
  00000011 ---->1 odd indexed bit is turned on
  00000100 ----> 0 odd indexed bits is turned on

 */
int array2[4];
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    array2[i] = ODD(array1[i]);
}

for(j=0; j<4; j++)
{
    printf("Array2: %d\n",array2[j]);
}




  return 0;
}
```

I have no idea why I got the following errors:

```
odd.c: In function ���main���:
odd.c:4:5: error: expected expression before ���int���
 int count = 0;\

odd.c:34:19: note: in expansion of macro ���ODD���
   array2[i] = ODD(array1[i]);
               ^

odd.c:8:13: error: ���count��� undeclared (first use in this function)
         count++;\
         ^
```

count is declared so I don't know what is the problem with it.

Why did I get these errors and how can I fix them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got an error because a macro is not a function. It's a token expansion mechanism, and it expands to the following nonsense:

```
array2[i] = int count = 0;
while(array1[i]>>1)\
{\
    if( ((array1[i]>>1)%2) == 1)\
        count++;\
}\
```

Write it as function, and then you can treat it as though it's returning an actual result:

```
int odd(int n) {
  int count = 0;
  while(n>>1)
  {
    if( ((n>>1)%2) == 1)
        count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

---

If you insist on writing this with a macro, then you'll need to restructure it:

```
#define ODD(n, res) do { \
  int count = 0; \
  while(n>>1)\
  {\
    if( ((n>>1)%2) == 1)\
      count++;\
  }\
  (res) = count;\
} while(0)
```

To define a variable, you must introduce a scope, so a do while loop is added for that effect. This particular loop construct has the nice feature of not producing a warning about empty statements when you write a statement terminator after the macro invocation (`ODD(...);`).

The location target for the result should be passed as another argument to the macro, like so:

```
ODD(array1[i], array2[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
@StoryTeller

Comment: @Tree - Like my edit suggests. And also be mindful the right shifting signed integers has implementation defined results.

Comment: Thank you. The thing is, I'm interested in writing this as a macro. How can I achieve this? @StoryTeller

Comment: @Tree - Why are interested in writing this as a macro?

Comment: I wanted to practice and stumbled across this exercise, and I'm curious @StoryTeller

Comment: @Tree - Fine, I wrote it up if you wish to tinker with it. Just remember that when you write real applications, prefer functions first and second.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @StoryTeller 
I'd like to ask a few things.
So variables in macros have to be declared inside a block?
I'm a bit confused,the statement array2[i] = ODD(array1[i]);
is actually

array2[i] = do { \
  int count = 0; \
  while(n>>1)\
  {\
    if( ((n>>1)%2) == 1)\
      count++;\
  }\
  (res) = count;
} while(0)
How come res is going to be stored in array2[i]? Is while loop allowed inside macros?

Comment: @Tree - Run you code though the pre-processor alone. For gcc it involves just invoking it with `gcc -E myfile.c`. You'll see what I mean by macro expansion, and how `res` **is** `array2[i]`. I've also corrected the expansion part in your erroneous code, so you can see how `n` is replaced there.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean though the pre-processor alone? How come we write this: while(0), it seems to me like the code is never going to execute that way, since 0 is like false. Where's my mistake? I'd be glad if you could explain more about the modifications that were done, as I don't really understand them. @StoryTeller

Comment: @Tree - Your mistake seems to be learning from tinkering instead of from a well structured book or tutorial. The preporcessor is the first stage in compiling a C file. And the loop is a do while loop, that always preforms the first iteration, and only then checks the condition.

Comment: My mistake is not from tinkering, I know what the C processor is, and I know what a do while loop is. What I don't understand is why these modifications were made @StoryTeller

Comment: @Tree - If you want to understand the scope, remove it. Then write a simple program that just invokes the macro twice in the same scope, something like `ODD(...); ODD(...);`. Once you learn why the scope is a good idea, try other scope constructs and turn your compiler warnings way up (for gcc `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror`), and you'll see why I chose the do while loop. The zero is there for the sole purpose of running the code once, as opposed to in a loop.